# Price Comparison Site with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, comparison, fuzzy-comparison

I am looking to build a price comparison website and use Elastic search to help me do so. The products that we will be comparing from different vendors will have different product titles, brand names etc. What I would like to know is, will I be able to match 2 products that are the same based on specific parts of their product title using elastic search. An example being these 4 product titles:

1) Apple Iphone 7 Black 64GB
2) Matte Black Iphone Case
3) 64GB Black I-phone
4) Apple Iphone Charger

If a user on our site clicks on the Apple Iphone 7 Black Product -> I will then query Elastic Search to find all the Apple Iphone 7 Black products and return them and their data back to the site. But I would only want products 1 & 3 to be returned.

Is this doable with Elastic Search? And if so could anyone show me a rough outline of what JSON needs to be sent for this kind or query?

Thanks

Comment: It should be but would take some work. One approach would be to make title an analyzed field (I would use the standard analyzer which is good for most western languages) and add a field  to hold product type(phone, case, charger..., granularity depends on your need). Then you can use term query on title field and match query on product type field (both inside a bool query with must class)

Comment: Correction use match on title field and term on product type field

Comment: This is not as easy as the answer/comments suggest. Name matching is not a trivial problem and will always lead to edge cases failing. Having said that, you can keep improving your match queries by using multi-fields in elasticsearch.
Your product name field needs to be analyzed in multiple ways and your query should add the score from matches on these fields. 
An excellent link to make you appreciate the kind of problems you'll face and a good starting point is found here: https://www.rosette.com/blog/fuzzy-search-names-in-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

Very good project. I think you need similar product which matches most field or you can query phrase match to query and return similar product. Here is your code to find similar product

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "ids" : ["12345"],
            "fields" : ["field_1", "field_2"],
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }

}
```

Phrase Match Query

```
{
    "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {"multi_match": {
                        "fields" : ["field_1", "field_2"],
                        "query": "Apple Iphone 7 Black 64GB",
                        "type": "phrase"
                                    }}
                                   ],
                    "must_not": [
                   {
                       "ids": {
                       "values": ["12345"]
                    }
               }
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

If you need fuzzy match then replace

```
"type": "phrase"
```

to

```
"fuzziness" : "AUTO"
```